# React - displaying images side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

**QUESTION**

I have a few photos saved as `png` files that are in the same folder as the React component and are imported correctly as well.

How and what would be a good practice way to display all the images, let's say there are 4 images, in their proper box shown in the picture below and have them be displayed side by side, along with their name/price aligned below the image.

Similar to craigslist's gallery setting when looking at posts with images.

Ex:

`<img src={Logo} alt=“website logo”/>`

`<img src={Mogo} alt=“website mogo”/>`

`<img src={Jogo} alt=“website jogo”/>`

`<img src={Gogo} alt=“website gogo”/>`

Could I do something with `products.map((product, index, image?))...`?

**CODE**

```
const Product = props => {
  const { product, children } = props;
  return (
    <div className="products">
      {product.name} ${product.price}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [products] = useState([
    { name: "Superman Poster", price: 10 },
    { name: "Spider Poster", price: 20 },
    { name: "Bat Poster", price: 30 }
  ]);

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = index => {
    setCart(cart.concat(products[index]));
  };

  const calculatePrice = () => {
    return cart.reduce((price, product) => price + product.price, 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Shopping cart example using React Hooks</h2>
      <hr />
      {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          <button onClick={() => addToCart(index)}>Add to cart</button>
        </Product>
      ))}
      YOUR CART TOTAL: ${calculatePrice()}
      {cart.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          {" "}
        </Product>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can add those images inside your `product` component. Since they are related to that component. And you can wrap all your products with a div and then use css `flex` to align them

Comment: @SifatHaque so to start, something like this? if this is along the right path, how do i extract the images from the same folder and have the be displayed along the rest of the name/price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the list of products with a div (`<div className="productsContainer">`), and display it as a flex with wrap.

Set the width of the items (`products`) to `50%` or less.

To render the image, render the `<img>` tag as one of the children, or add it directly to the product. Also change the data to include the `src`.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Product = ({ product, children }) => (
  <div className="products">
    {product.name} ${product.price}
    {children}
  </div>
);

function App() {
  const [products] = useState([
    { name: "Superman Poster", price: 10, logo: 'https://picsum.photos/150/150?1' },
    { name: "Spider Poster", price: 20, logo: 'https://picsum.photos/150/150?2' },
    { name: "Bat Poster", price: 30, logo: 'https://picsum.photos/150/150?3' }
  ]);

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = index => {
    setCart(cart.concat(products[index]));
  };

  const calculatePrice = () => {
    return cart.reduce((price, product) => price + product.price, 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Shopping cart example using React Hooks</h2>
      <hr />
      <div className="productsContainer">
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <Product key={index} product={product}>           
            <img src={product.logo} alt="website logo" />
            
            <button onClick={() => addToCart(index)}>Add to cart</button>
          </Product>
        ))}
      </div>
      YOUR CART TOTAL: ${calculatePrice()}
      {cart.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          {" "}
        </Product>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.productsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.products img {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: nice, appreciate that, in my attempt below, would that be a right path in having those images being displayed?

Comment: What path or url would you add if the images are in the same folder and not an endpoint.

Comment: Relative path, but depends on your build.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to display those side by side you can display it by giving css classes `flex-row` for horizontal view and `flex-column` for vertical view in the main div component

Comment: gotcha but can i throw the images in that same products array and work with that somehow?

Comment: yes , you can throw them in the array and work it . basically the only that will matter is that particular class should be applied to that particular component .

Answer (score 0):

```
const Product = props => {
  const { product, children, image } = props;
  return (
    <div className="products">
      {product.name} ${product.price} ${product.image}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`products.map((product, index, image?))...?`

Something along the lines of this?